# Sort the string elements based on lenght without java predefined functions?

Tags: java, string

This is my demo.jsp page.

```
<%
    String[] stringArray = {"google", "char", "char2", "0", "12", "zoombi", "integer"};
    String[] resutlArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
       if (stringArray[i].length() > stringArray[i + 1].length()) {

       }
    }
%>
```

Required output:`0 12 char char2 zoombi google integer`

How can i print like this?

Comment: Are you asking how to sort an array of Strings in order of length?  Or are you asking how to print Strings in JSP?

Comment: I'd suggest looking up something like "bubble sort" and see how you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the sorting algorithms like bubble sort, quick sort, merge sort etc.

for example:

```
    String[] stringArray = {"google", "char", "char2", "0", "12", "zoombi", "integer"};
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<stringArray.length;j++)
              if (stringArray[j].length() < stringArray[i].length()) {
                 String temp = stringArray[i];
                 stringArray[i] = stringArray[j];
                 stringArray[j]= temp;
             }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

Please do not copy-paste it blindly, first try to understand what it is doing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: For future consideration, if you want to deter copy-pasting, I'd write pseudocode (or insert a bug that prevents compilation)

Comment: If the StringArray ={"google", "char", "intchar", "stack", "India"};how can i get result as:char intchar India google stack

Comment: @ThazAhammad By using a sorting algorithm. Just like this answer provides.

Comment: this is not following the sorting criteria described in question `as intchar has 6 char and india has 5 char google has 6 char and stack has 5 char` you need to do something different in that case

Answer (score 0):

Supppse if the string is String[] stringArray = {"google", "char", "char2", "zoombi", "integer"}; if you want to sort the string based on starting character of word alphabatically then just change the if condition like this
 if (stringArray[j].compareToIgnoreCase(stringArray[i]) < 0).